# Unable to use loop to generate Firebase Cloud Functions HTTP Output

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use a loop to generate some content via Cloud Functions but I can't seem to get HTML to be stored as a variable.

I am following the documentation in https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions to try and generate a dynamic page using cloud functions.

In the example they use:

```
res.status(200).send(`<!doctype html>
    <head>
      <title>Time</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      ${'BONG '.repeat(hours)}
    </body>
  </html>`);
```

however if I try store a part of the html in a different variable it fails: 
eg

```
var header = '<!doctype html>
        <head>
          <title>Time</title>
        </head>' // Generates an error
res.status(200).send(header) // Doesn't run
```

How do I break up the content to generate the output dynamically?

Comment: Since you fixed the problem Doug mentioned, I'll assume that didn't cause the problem. In that case: what **is** the problem? Is there an error message?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing an `=` in the assignment to `header`.

```
var header = '<!doctype html>
        <head>
          <title>Time</title>
        </head>' // Generates an error
res.status(200).send(header) // Doesn't run
```

Comment: Hiya - thanks for the feedback - however that was a copy paste error  I  am just struggling with a node js error trying to  get firebase serve working then I can try regenerate the error nessgev. Thanks a lot Doug !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was using the wrong quotation marks to store the header.  I was using singe quote whereas I should have been using the backtick quotations symbol.

I assume this automatically escapes any content within it.  So my example should have read as:

```
var header = `<!doctype html>
        <head>
          <title>Time</title>
        </head>` 
res.status(200).send(header) // Works Great!
```